# Catch return value of bulk insert in SQLite room

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, bulkinsert

Let's say I have the following insertAll function:

```
@Insert
void insertDogs(List<Dog> dogs);
```

And

```
public long[] insertDogs(List<Dog> dogs) {
    return appDatabase.dogDao().insertDogs(dogs)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //causes Cannot resolve method 'subscribeOn(io.reactivex.Scheduler)'
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

What is the correct return value of bulk insert should be?
If I want to receive the new created ids of the dogs, I receive the above mentioned error.

Is it enough to just put try catch outside insertDogs function, as subscribeOn does not work as it seems for bulk inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using :-

```
@Insert
long[] insertDogs(List<Dog> dogs);
```